# what is pandas dataframe.ne method and why it is used ?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When i check about this pandas `dataframe.ne` method, the documentation says its a wrapper for flexible comparison. I cannot find any proper example about this in pandas documentation. Why we use this `df.ne` and how it makes easier or flexible while doing data manipulation ? Is it possible to give me one example with `df.ne` and without `df.ne` for the same approach, which will help me to understand ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.3/pandas/core/ops.py#L1579-L1597) for the implementation of `DataFrame.ne`. The code is not too hard to understand.

Essentially, `DataFrame.ne` provides a more flexible way of performing inequality comparison. You can also specify additional arguments which is not possible when using the `!=` operator.

Examples:

1. `DataFrame.ne` allows comparison between two dataframes where the indexes don't align

   ```
   df0 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [0.1, 0.3, 0.9], 'c': [2,4,6]}, index=list('abc'))

   df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [3,2,1], 'b': [0.9, 0.3, 0.1], 'c': [6,4,2]}, index=list('cba'))

   df0.ne(df1)
   # outputs:
          a      b      c
   a  False  False  False
   b  False  False  False
   c  False  False  False
   ```

   but `df0 != df1` raises the following error:

   ```
   ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
   ```
2. `DataFrame.ne` accepts a series & the arguments `axis` and `level`.

   ```
   s1 = pd.Series([1,2,3], index=list('abc'))

   df0.ne(s1, axis=0)
          a     b     c
   a  False  True  True
   b  False  True  True
   c  False  True  True

   df0.ne(s1, axis=1)

          a     b     c
   a  False  True  True
   b   True  True  True
   c   True  True  True
   ```

   The latter may be gotten through `df0 != s1` as well, but not the former
3. `DataFrame.ne` also accepts a scalar as argument

   ```
   df0.ne(1)
   # outputs a dataframe where all values are true
          a     b     c
   a  False  True  True
   b   True  True  True
   c   True  True  True
   ```

Answer (score 2):

df.ne is also used for any column check to be performed.
Example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4.],'two' : [4., 3., 2., 1.]})

    one  two
    0  1.0  4.0
    1  2.0  3.0
    2  3.0  2.0
    3  4.0  1.0

not3=df['two'].ne(3).sum()
```

not3=3

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `ne` stand for (Not equal to). This method is part of the core python `operator overloading implementation` magic method named __ne__().

Pandas derived this method straightforward from core python implementation. and customized it for Series and Dataframe for condition checks.
 It returns Boolean Value to check condition.

**example:-**

```
ne(a, b) is equivalent to a != b
```

**Example code for Series:-**

```
>>> a = pd.Series([1, 1, 1, np.nan], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
>>> b = pd.Series([1, np.nan, 1, np.nan], index=['a', 'b', 'd', 'e'])
>>> a
a    1.0
b    1.0
c    1.0
d    NaN
dtype: float64
>>> b
a    1.0
b    NaN
d    1.0
e    NaN
dtype: float64
>>> a.ne(b,fill_value=0)
a    False
b     True
c     True
d     True
e     True
dtype: bool
>>>
```